# Windows 10 throws 0x80071a91 every single time

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I get this error in Windows 10 every single time I try to install cumulative or Adobe Flash Player updates (not for Office and other minor updates). I remove C:\Winodws\SoftwareDistribution in safe mode, restart and it updates successfully only to show the same error the next time.

Do you have any idea about what's going on?

Comment: [Windows 10 Error code: 0x80071A91 - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-error-code-0x80071a91/6799b822-7cc3-4286-a2a8-184277e7bc34)

Comment: In the elevated cmd run: fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\

Comment: If the above doesn't help:
1. cd /d %SystemRoot%\System32\SMI\Store\Machine
2. attrib -s -h *
3. del *.blf 
4. del *.regtrans-ms